# OSError - cannot import geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas, python-3, osgeo, pip

While trying to import geopandas error occurs:

> Exception has occurred: OSError Could not find lib geos_c.dll
>   or load any of its variants [].

I downloaded GDAL and fiona for Python 3.7 from this website https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/?fbclid=IwAR09Axx2Z6e7tMk8ITEeVePOSX4G6vhsyTNdSGjZfiozAb0Qj57xx6lrdMA#gdal

Then I did "pip install geopandas" and pip works but while importing geopandas in script it still doesn't work, even after installing OSGeo4W.
I'm using Windows 10.
What should I do to be able to use geopandas?

Comment: Hey, welcome to GIS SE. If you don't have any specific limitations to do so, I'd suggest you [downloading Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/) and using it to install `geopandas`. It is as easy as opening a command prompt and running `conda install geopandas`.

Comment: And if you want to keep using wheels, you will need to install Shapely as well from the same place where you downloaded fiona wheels. (but I also recommend Anaconda)